# Why does using this deleted function work?

Tags: c++

```
struct S {
    S() {}
    S (const S &) = delete;
};

void f1 (S s) {}
void f2 (S &s) {}

int main() {
    S s;

    f2(s);
}
```

Since `S(S &s)` is deleted, why does using `f2` not throw an error since when it was declared it passes in the arguments `S &s`? When I use `f1(s)` it throws an error. I've looked at the definition of deleted functions and I thought this would throw an error, but it doesn't. Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lets have a look at `S`:

```
struct S {
    S() {}                   // default constructor
    S (const S &) = delete;  // copy-constructor
};
```

What you have here is a type that can be constructed, but cannot be copied.

Now lets take a look at your functions:

```
void f1 (S s1) {}    // creates a local copy of its parameter
void f2 (S &s2) {}   // takes a reference to the parameter
```

When you call `f1(s)`, the function tries to create a copy of `s` - but your type `S` forbids copying - that's why this does not work.

When you call `f2(s)`, the function creates a reference to its parameter - so whatever you do inside `f2` with `s2` is done directly to the original object `s`. There is no way a class can prevent anybody to take a reference of the object.

Comment: What confuses me is that when I see `S(const S &) = delete` I think: *Don't allow the user to do anything like* `S &s` then when I see `f2(S &s2)` work I don't understand the logic.

Comment: yes, I can see how this might be confusing ... but you have to remember that constructors (especially those with single parameter) are _special_.

Answer (score 10):

Because passing by reference doesn't create a copy (which is what `f2` uses).

`f1`, on the other hand, takes a pass-by-value parameter, which makes a copy.

Comment: So `S(S &s) = delete;` means don't allow to pass by reference?

Comment: @user6607 no, because pass by reference works. It doesn't allow pass by value.

Comment: @user6607 no, what do you mean. `f2` takes a parameter by reference, no copy is involved, and it works. `f1` takes a parameter by value, a copy is attempted, but fails since the copy constructor is deleted. What's the problem?